# how to mimic Chrome's "save page as complete webpage" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to enable the user to export my website as a downloadable folder/zip that can be accessed offline, while maintaining:

1. folder structure (images/css)
2. interactivity (JS navigation, state, etc.)
3. relative links

basically do what Chrome's webpage saving feature already does well. What would be the best approach to trigger it from javascript?

Comment: Can the user just use the existing save feature? What's the point of implementing this in js?

Comment: The user may not be aware of this option or may not save it as the correct format